# How to make permanent storage for an iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, storage

I am doing an application where user can select buildings on the map and save them in the list. Everything is fine but I need to save users selection after app closing.

```
func action(_ gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer) { // GESTURE RECOGNIZER FUNCTION

    if gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began {

        let touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self.map)

        let newCoordinate = self.map.convert(touchPoint, toCoordinateFrom: self.map)

        let location = CLLocation(latitude: newCoordinate.latitude, longitude: newCoordinate.longitude)

        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in


            var title = ""

            if (error == nil) {

                if let p = placemarks?[0] {


                    var subThoroughfare:String = ""
                    var thoroughfare:String = ""

                    if p.subThoroughfare != nil {

                        subThoroughfare = p.subThoroughfare!

                    }

                    if p.thoroughfare != nil {

                        thoroughfare = p.thoroughfare!

                    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the building ID into an array, and save that array into UserDefaults.

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(value: buildingIds, forKey: "myBuildingIds")
```

When you open the app, simply ask:

```
if let myBuildingArrays = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "myBuildingIds"){
//And here you iterate each value of the array to load them into your list.
}
```

More information: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults